# How to set the vector's bg color without using external libraries?

Tags: android, vector, background-color, android-drawable

I have a `<vector>` element as follows:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M20 .....4z"/>
</vector>
```

I want to change the color when in dark or light mode.

I tried to `tint` the drawble

I tried to change `android:fillColor="@android:color/transparent"`

but I always see the background is white.

How can I change this filler color?

What's the meaning of `fillPath`? is this the vector background color?

If not, how would you set the vector's bg color without using external libraries?

[VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable) doesn't explain much about the fillColor

.

dark mode colors:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Path is the shape, fillColor is the color inside the shape, actually set in white in your code

Comment: Thanks, how can I set the colors to be like in the added image?

Comment: That's depends on the vector path data, try to change the white color in fillColor and look what it change

Comment: You should try to remove the tint attribute too

Comment: change of "fillColor" didn't change anything. Why?